# How to use "display: table" to merge two rows, css?

Tags: html, css

I try to show following object with 3 images:

```
...........
|    |    |
|  1 |    |
|----|  2 |
|  3 |    |
|    |    |
|____|____|
```

I use `display` style:

```
    .table {
        display: table;
    }
    .row {
        display: table-row;
    } 
   .cell {
        display: table-cell;
    }
```

So far I got this:

[image]

```
<div style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="display: table;">
                <div class="row">                        
                    <div class="cell" style="height: 100%;">
                        <img style="height: 38.5%; display:block;" src="img/group_6.png"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cell" style="width: 37px;overflow: hidden;">
                         <img style="height: 74px; display: block; margin-left: -18.5px;" 
                              src="img/group_6.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div  class="cell" style="height: 100%;">
                        <img style="height: 38.5%; display:block;"  src="img/group_6.png" />
                    </div>                       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to achieve the view I posted?

Thank you,

Comment: `display:table-cell` doesn't quite work like that. A JSFiddle would be very helpful though.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I use list of items for mobile

Comment: I don't think CSS table-layout can help in this problem. You have to use HTML table-layout (although many discussions suggest it's not recommended), you may have to use another kind of layout, such as a simple floating layout.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/sLx8j/

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name of images. For the image available in the right side it might be possible that you've to adjust: align or top or bottom  margins. Adjust them according to the requirement. I've created the borders which will help you to adjust images appropriately. Once done please remove them. Kindly check and verify....

```
 <html>
    <style>
    .table {
            display: table;
        }
        .row {
            display: table-row;
        } 
       .cell {
            display: table-cell;
        } 
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="table">

                <div class="cell" style="border: 10px solid;">
                    <div class="row"  style="border: 10px solid;">
                        <img style="height: 38.5%; display: block;" src="xyz.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"  style="border: 10px solid;">
                        <img style="height: 38.5%; display: block;" src="pqrs.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"  style="border: 10px solid; height:auto; width:100%">
                    <img align="middle" style="width:20%; height: auto; display: inline-block;" src="abcd.jpg" />
                </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```